# System redirected to same login page after login in Odoo12

Tags: authentication, redirect, odoo, odoo-12

I am working on Odoo12. when I log in for odoo then it redirects me on the same login page and all login options available for me. So, the problem is related to redirect. I have tested the code and got that request.params['login_success'] show 'false' value in print. My python code is below.

```
@http.route(website=True, auth="public")
def web_login(self, redirect=None, *args, **kw):
    response = super(CustomAuthSignupHome, self).web_login(redirect=redirect, *args, **kw)
    print('Loginnn', request.params['login_success'])
    if not redirect and request.params['login_success']:
        user = request.env['res.users'].browse(request.uid)
        if user.has_group('base.group_user'):
            if user.partner_id.company_type == 'company':
                redirect = '/dashboard'
            else:
                redirect = b'/web?' + request.httprequest.query_string
        return http.redirect_with_hash(redirect)
    return response
```

So, anyone can suggest the solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any authentication related custom module installed on database?

Comment: hello younis, problem solved. missed else condition for rediretion

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. missed else condition for redirection

```
@http.route(website=True, auth="public")
    def web_login(self, redirect=None, *args, **kw):
        response = super(CustomAuthSignupHome, self).web_login(redirect=redirect, *args, **kw)
        if not redirect and request.params['login_success']:
            user = request.env['res.users'].browse(request.uid)
            if user.has_group('base.group_user'):
                if user.partner_id.company_type == 'company':
                    redirect = '/dashboard'
                else:
                    redirect = b'/web?' + request.httprequest.query_string
            else:
                redirect = '/my/account'
            return http.redirect_with_hash(redirect)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a model that inherits from res.user and modify the action_id with a compute.

```
class InheritResUsers(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.users'
    _inherit = ['res.users']

# Nouveaux champs

action_id = fields.Many2one('ir.actions.actions', string='Home Action', compute='get_home_page')

def get_home_page(self):

for project in self:
    # we position ourselves in the ir.actions.act_window model
    tasks = self.env['ir.actions.act_window']
    #we search for the specific view by using the name and une xml_id
    task_ids = tasks.search(
        [['xml_id', '=', '  project.open_view_project_all'], ['name', '=', 'Projects']])
    for task in task_ids:  # Browse the table by adding the page id to the inherited action_id field
        self.action_id=task.id
InheritResUsers()
```

Here I redirect to the home page of my module.